# What are the correct translations for these Marathi spiritual sentences

Tags: brahman, translation, paramatma

Anyone who speak Marathi here?

Which one is the correct translation of these Marathi sentences "निर्विकल्पापर्यंत विद्यानंद आहे. त्यापलीकडे वस्तू आहे,"? These Marathi sentences came from an Advaita-related book by a spiritual teacher known as Siddharameshwar.

Is it "Up to Nirvikalpa is Vidyananda. Beyond that is the thing" or "There is Vidyananda up to Nirvikalpa. The thing is beyond that"?

The first moment we look at these English translations, both seem correct but the second English translation, we are not sure whether the "thing" is beyond Vidyananda or Nirvikalpa. "The thing" or vastu here referred to Parabrahman or Para Purusha. So, this created some confusions. I believe the first English translation is the correct one which is beyond Vidyananda. If Parabrahman is beyond Nirvikalpa, then the Advaitins are just wasting their time to get self-realization by meditating.

Comment: Verbatim Reply from a Pune Konkanastha Brahmin: "वस्तु": आत्मा, परमात्मा
This was a term used by yogis.
Reference: 
Swami Samarth: " पंचपत्रात वस्तु आहे असे तू म्हणतेस, तर याचा अर्थ काय?" 
पंचपात्र was human body & "वस्तु" was आत्मा.
Here: निर्विकल्प is a state of samadhi; this is "विद्यानंद"..perhaps a result of विद्या(knowledge,skill, talent,technique, art..). "वस्तु" is still beyond it, not confined in any process.

Answer (score 0):

He is saying there is something beyond Nirvikalpa samadhi.
Ramana maharishi explains this.

[Longest samadhi state of Ramana maharshi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46332/longest-samadhi-state-of-ramana-maharshi)

Bhagwan Rajneesh says different realized souls express their state differently.

https://www.osho.com/osho-online-library/osho-talks/j.-krishnamurti-ramakrishna-experience-5e1a4fd2-430?p=82ce9cae38965291dd9a617268d38d15

caveat:  these are all just words unless one achieves Samadhi.